# how deploy asp.net project which use Crystal Report 2008

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have created ASP.net Web application which uses Crystal Report to show reports. Now i want to publish this project to server. I have installed full version of Crystal Reports 2008 on server. It works and showing up reports.

How can be made Crystal Reports to run on server without installing whole version? 
Is there any standalone host for it or runtime which can handle crystal reports templates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports has special [runtime packages](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp) for this usage.

Comment: i have watched this site. I'll watch again. Thanks